# hadoop give output after all reducers are done

Tags: java, hadoop, counter, cloudera

in the first part of the code I set up a number of arrays to keep track of some values like this:

```
  @Override 
  public void configure(JobConf conf){
       top5=new String[5];
      counttop5=new int[5]
      }
```

Now after some code from the reducer I want to output the content of the top to the output file, however, in order to do this I have created a close() functions :

```
  @Override 
      public void close(){
         //what goes here? 
      }
```

However as you can see there is nothing to call to as the output is defined in the reducer methode.
While the code itself is quite long here is the data signature of the methodes :

```
    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Writable> {
private  static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Writable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Writable, Text, Writable> {

      static ArrayList<String> files;
          static String[] top5;
          static int[] counttop5;
          int reducedterms;
          public void configure(JobConf conf){
              files= new ArrayList<String>();
              top5=new String[5];
              reducedterms=0; 
              counttop5=new int[5];


          }
          @Override 
          public void close(){
             //what goes here? 
          }

          public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Writable> values, OutputCollector<Text, Writable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    }
```

Anybody know a fix?

Comment: By "first part of the code" you mean inside the mapper or before that?

Comment: No this within the reducer code but first part of code just means the first part of this solution.

Comment: Thanks, but it would be very helpful if you could provide the code for the whole reducer, so that it is more clear what is your `OutputFormat` and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have added the data signatures of the functions however the files are quite large and I doubt it will fit.

Comment: Thanks (and sorry for the noise) but is extending `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer` instead of  implementing `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer` interface out of the question? If no, I think I have an answer.

Comment: Well it would be an option but it sounds like a lot of work. What is your answer?

Comment: Extending instead of implementing worked thank you!

Comment: @ArtemTsikiridis should write an answer then, and you can accept it, and award the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer using `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` classes. The API is a bit different from the code you present as we now extend the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer` base class instead of implementing the `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer` interface, but here is a straightforward way of doing what you need:

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Writable, Text, Writable> {

  static ArrayList<String> files;
  static String[] top5;
  static int[] counttop5;
  int reducedterms;

  //setup method instead of configure
  public void setup(Context context){
          files= new ArrayList<String>();
          top5=new String[5];
          reducedterms=0; 
          counttop5=new int[5];
  }

  //In cleanup you may access the write method
  @Override 
  public void cleanup(Context context){
         // Use top5 and counttop5 the way you see fit
         // Use context.write() to pass them ahead!
  }

      public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Writable> values, Context context) throws IOException {
}
```